# How to make my reducer reusable using Redux toolkit?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

How can I make my reducer be reusable in other slices?

For example, I have this reducer in my signinSlice and I want this also to be used in my signupSlice without copying and pasting it to it.

```
    reducers: {
        RESET_INITIAL_STATE: (state) => {
      state.status = "idle";
    },
  },
```

The reason why I'm asking this is I want to reduce or prevent the duplicated code all over in my other slices. By the way, I'm using redux-toolkit

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, You should not factorize your reducer but you can just declare a function anywhere

```
export const resetInitialState = (state) => state.status = "idle"
```

and in both slices:

```
import { resetInitialState } from '...'

reducers: {
  RESET_INITIAL_STATE: resetInitialState
}
```